# (Wordpress) Is it possible to use short codes from a 3rd party plugin from within my own plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I have a plugin which grabs the post content and sends it to a 3rd party API as html, which should send with all the short codes resolved (translated to it's corresponding html). However, unless I'm mistaken, my plugin seems to only resolve native short codes or those declared in my theme. I need it to resolve all short codes declared in other plugins, but those don't appear listed when my plugin queries what short codes it has available to it.

I feel there must be a way, even if replicating what ever Wordpress itself does for example when you "Preview" a post, it seems to know how to resolve all short codes.

What am I missing here to achieve the behaviour I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: how are you trying to call the shortcode in your plugin?

Comment: If you go directly to the post preview, all shortcodes are executed? But if you echo get_the_content() shortcodes are not executed? It doesn't have sense. Are you using the WP function get_the_content ? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content

Comment: I'm calling get_post() to get the content, and then applying:

$post_content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content);

in addition calling

$post_content = do_shortcode($post_content);

Comment: That link points out that get_the_content() does not expand short codes. I am finding that some short codes are being expanded, but not those declared in other plugins. Any idea as to why that might be. Or any suggestions how could amend the above code, or anything I can do to give you more feedback/info?